# SQLite is stubborn on using the suboptimal row ID index

Tags: performance, sqlite, indexing, full-text-search, query-optimization

Let's say I have a following database structure:

```sql
CREATE TABLE "posts" (
  "id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
  "isDeleted" INTEGER,
  "isPublished" INTEGER,
  "publishTs" INTEGER,
  "updateTs" INTEGER,
  "title" TEXT,
  "contentJson" JSON
);

CREATE INDEX posts_defaultView ON "posts" (publishTs, updateTs)
WHERE
  isPublished IS NOT NULL
  AND isDeleted IS NULL;

CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE "_fts_posts" USING fts5("title", "contentPlain");
```

My goal is to filter out the items matching an FTS query, but also meeting some other non-FTS criteria. Something like this:

```sql
SELECT
  *
FROM
  posts
  JOIN _fts_posts ON posts.rowId = _fts_posts.rowId
WHERE
  publishTs <= ?
  AND isPublished IS NOT NULL
  AND isDeleted IS NULL
  AND _fts_posts = ?
ORDER BY
  publishTs,
  updateTs
LIMIT
  10;
```

The problem is that the JOIN clause is messing up the query planner. Despite having a great index that covers both non-FTS filter and sorting, it goes for a following plan:

```
QUERY PLAN
|--SCAN _fts_posts VIRTUAL TABLE INDEX 0:M2
|--SEARCH posts USING INTEGER PRIMARY KEY (rowid=?)
`--USE TEMP B-TREE FOR ORDER BY
```

This strategy is suboptimal especially if the FTS part of the filter returns a broad result – then thousands of records have to be filtered and sorted manually.

I've been looking for the best way to avoid this issue and it turned out that the best approach so far is to simply disable the indexing in the join part using a `+` (`JOIN _fts_posts ON +posts.rowId = _fts_posts.rowId`).

Then the query plan changes like this:

```
QUERY PLAN
|--SEARCH posts USING INDEX posts_defaultView (publishTs<?)
`--SCAN _fts_posts VIRTUAL TABLE INDEX 0:M2=
```

When the FTS part of the filter is broad, the time difference is ~30x (and in a real-life DB it's closer to 1000x, probably due to `json_extract` clauses in the filter).

This solution does not satisfy me though, as the side effect is that if the FTS filter is narrow, then the whole `posts_defaultView` index has to be scanned. The time difference in such a scenario is ~500x in favor of using the row ID index.

Therefore, I am trying to better understand the query planner's behavior, and I have some questions:

1. If the first step is to `SCAN _fts_posts VIRTUAL TABLE INDEX 0:M2`, the planner should be able to know how large the FTS part of filter is, and basing on that estimate the usefulness of querying by row ID. If the filter is broad and covers i.e. 80% of IDs, the row ID match should be considered a lower quality index in comparison to the other one, that perfectly matches the rest of the query. Why does it not happen?
2. Even if the query planner is not able to estimate the likelihood of matching a row ID, it could make use of the fact that row ID is a part of index by default. So for some reason the planner decides that it's better to use the row ID index and manually filter out by 3 other criteria and sort by 2 other criteria, rather than loop through the sorted index and just filter it out by 1 criterion, which is row ID (directly available in the index). Why?
3. I was trying to fix the problem mentioned in the question #1 by using the `likelihood` function, but it does not affect the query planner at all. Changing the `JOIN` part into `WHERE likelihood(rowId IN (SELECT rowId FROM _fts_posts WHERE _fts_posts = ?), 1.0)` does not change anything in the query plan, even though `1.0` should flag this part of the filter as pretty useless index-wise. Why?

Thanks in advance for your help :).

Comment: Try running [`ANALYZE`](https://sqlite.org/lang_analyze.html) on the populated database to see if that helps?

Comment: @Shawn I've just tried, and it seems like it's even worse now. Adding a `+` now leads to `SCAN posts` instead of expected `SEARCH posts USING INDEX posts_defaultView (publishTs<?)`. The index is still in place though, as removing the FTS join completely still leads to using the `posts_defaultView` index.